# How fix this null check issue?

Tags: dart

Dart Language:

This is plugin issue
xmpp_stone plugin
I can't fix this issue
anyone known please replay
[![enter image description here]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHe0O.png

Dart Language:

This is plugin issue
xmpp_stone plugin
I can't fix this issue
anyone known please replay
[![enter image description here]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHe0O.png

This is full code issue in xmpp_stone plugin

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:xmpp_stone/src/logger/Log.dart';
import 'package:console/console.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:xmpp_stone/xmpp_stone.dart' as xmpp;
import 'package:image/image.dart' as image;
final String TAG = 'example';

class ExampleConnectionStateChangedListener implements xmpp.ConnectionStateChangedListener {
  late xmpp.Connection _connection;
  late xmpp.MessagesListener _messagesListener;

  StreamSubscription<String>? subscription;

  ExampleConnectionStateChangedListener(xmpp.Connection connection, xmpp.MessagesListener messagesListener) {
    _connection = connection;
    _messagesListener = messagesListener;
    _connection.connectionStateStream.listen(onConnectionStateChanged);
  }

  @override
  void onConnectionStateChanged(xmpp.XmppConnectionState state) {
    if (state == xmpp.XmppConnectionState.Ready) {
      Log.d(TAG, 'Connected');
     _connection.getMamModule().queryAll();
      var vCardManager = xmpp.VCardManager(_connection);
      vCardManager.getSelfVCard().then((vCard) {
        if (vCard != null) {
          Log.d(TAG, 'Your info' + vCard.buildXmlString());
        }
      });
      var messageHandler = xmpp.MessageHandler.getInstance(_connection);
      var rosterManager = xmpp.RosterManager.getInstance(_connection);
      messageHandler.messagesStream.listen(_messagesListener.onNewMessage);
      sleep(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      var receiver = 'yyy@gmail.com';
      var receiverJid = xmpp.Jid.fromFullJid(receiver);
      rosterManager.addRosterItem(xmpp.Buddy(receiverJid)).then((result) {
        if (result.description != null) {
          print("TAG, 'add roster'" + result.description!);
        }
      });
      sleep(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      vCardManager.getVCardFor(receiverJid).then((vCard) {
        if (vCard != null) {
          print("TAG, 'Receiver info'" + vCard.buildXmlString());
          if (vCard != null && vCard.image != null) {
            var file = File('test456789.jpg')..writeAsBytesSync(image.encodeJpg(vCard.image!));
            print("TAG, IMAGE SAVED TO: ${file.path}");
          }
        }
      });
      var presenceManager = xmpp.PresenceManager.getInstance(_connection);
      presenceManager.presenceStream.listen(onPresence);

    }
  }

  void onPresence(xmpp.PresenceData event) {
    Log.d(TAG, 'presence Event from ' + event.jid!.fullJid! + ' PRESENCE: ' + event.showElement.toString());
  }
}

Stream<String> getConsoleStream() {
  return Console.adapter.byteStream().map((bytes) {
    var str = ascii.decode(bytes);
    str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
    return str;
  });
}

class ExampleMessagesListener implements xmpp.MessagesListener {

  @override
  void onNewMessage(xmpp.MessageStanza? message) {
    if (message!.body != null) {
      Log.d(TAG ,format(
          'New Message from {color.blue}${message.fromJid!.userAtDomain}{color.end} message: {color.red}${message.body}{color.end}'));
    }
  }

  @override
  void onChatMessage(xmpp.MessageStanza? message) {
    print(message);
    if (message!.body != null) {
      Log.d(TAG,format(
          'New Message from {color.blue}${message.fromJid!.userAtDomain}{color.end} message: {color.red}${message.body}{color.end}'));
    }
  }
}

sendmessageforxmpp(){
  var userAtDomain = 'xxx@gmail.com';

  var password = 'password';
  var jid = xmpp.Jid.fromFullJid(userAtDomain);
  var account = xmpp.XmppAccountSettings(userAtDomain, jid.local, 
 jid.domain, password, 5222, resource: 'xmppstone');
  var connection = xmpp.Connection(account);
  var receiver = 'yyy@gmail.com';
  var receiverJid = xmpp.Jid.fromFullJid(receiver);
Log.d(TAG, receiverJid.fullJid.toString());
  var messageHandler = 
   xmpp.MessageHandler.getInstance(connection); 
    messageHandler.sendMessage(receiverJid, "str");
}
```

Comment: What version of the `xmpp_stone` package are you using? Can you show us your code which is failing because of this? How are you initializing the code? Even better, write a small program that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: version: 0.3.3 @julemand101

Comment: @ManivannanKumar Can you click on the `[14 more...]` to expand the error and post the full stacktrace here?

Comment: @ManivannanKumar Can you please post the code of your application where you are making use of `xmpp_stone`? I have a suspicion that something is going wrong about stuff not being awaited on. And don't post the code as a screenshot! Post it as TEXT!!!

Comment: @ManivannanKumar Please edit your question with the relevant Dart code as text.

Comment: @ManivannanKumar I know. But the problem comes from the fact that the developer of the package have some assumptions of how the package are being used and you ends up using the package in another way. I have posted an answer which explains the core of the problem and a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not using `xmpp_stone` correctly and therefore ends up in a situation where the internal state of `xmpp_stone` does not match what the developer of the package have intended.

I do, however, think the package are badly designed in such a way that wrong usage are very likely to happen so I would not blame you for getting into trouble.

The problem is the following in your code:

```dart
var connection = xmpp.Connection(account);
// ..
var messageHandler = xmpp.MessageHandler.getInstance(connection);
messageHandler.sendMessage(receiverJid, "str");
```

You are here creating a `Connection` but the underlying socket are never created. The default value for the internal state of `Connection` are `XmppConnectionState.Idle`. But when you are later trying to `sendMessage`, your code ends up running this from the package:

```dart
  void write(message) {
    Log.xmppp_sending(message);
    if (isOpened()) {
      _socket!.write(message);
    }
  }

  bool isOpened() {
    return state != XmppConnectionState.Closed &&
        state != XmppConnectionState.ForcefullyClosed &&
        state != XmppConnectionState.Closing &&
        state != XmppConnectionState.SocketOpening;
  }
```

The `isOpened()` ends up returning `true` since it sees `XmppConnectionState.Idle` as an open state where messages are allowed to be sent.

But that is not the case here since we never asked `Connection` to open actually do any connection and therefore `_socket` ends up being `null`. Since the package are trying to do `!` on `null`, the application crashes.

For an actual solution, we can get inspired from the example implementation from `xmpp_dart`:

https://github.com/vukoye/xmpp_dart/blob/master/example/example.dart

We can here see they have a `connection.connect();` call. But, I am going to guess this really only works because the example are not going to use the connection right after this call. The problem is that it is implemented like the following:

```dart
  void connect() {
    if (_state == XmppConnectionState.Closing) {
      _state = XmppConnectionState.WouldLikeToOpen;
    }
    if (_state == XmppConnectionState.Closed) {
      _state = XmppConnectionState.Idle;
    }
    if (_state == XmppConnectionState.Idle) {
      openSocket();
    }
  }

  Future<void> openSocket() async {
    connectionNegotatiorManager.init();
    setState(XmppConnectionState.SocketOpening);
    try {
      return await Socket.connect(account.host ?? account.domain, account.port)
          .then((Socket socket) {
        // if not closed in meantime
        if (_state != XmppConnectionState.Closed) {
          setState(XmppConnectionState.SocketOpened);
```

So `connect()` returns `void` but calls `openSocket()` which does return  a `Future` that would be able to tell us when the connection are actually ready.

I would therefore instead suggest using `openSocket()` directly and make your `sendmessageforxmpp()` method `async` so we can `await` on the connection being open.

So your code should look like:

```dart
Future<void> sendmessageforxmpp() async {
  var userAtDomain = 'xxx@gmail.com';
  var password = 'password';
  
  var jid = xmpp.Jid.fromFullJid(userAtDomain);
  var account = xmpp.XmppAccountSettings(
      userAtDomain, jid.local, jid.domain, password, 5222,
      resource: 'xmppstone');

  var connection = xmpp.Connection(account);
  await connection.openSocket(); // <--- the important change :)

  var receiver = 'yyy@gmail.com';
  var receiverJid = xmpp.Jid.fromFullJid(receiver);
  Log.d(TAG, receiverJid.fullJid.toString());
  var messageHandler = xmpp.MessageHandler.getInstance(connection);
  messageHandler.sendMessage(receiverJid, "str");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually occurring when you use the bang operator (`!`) on a nullable value that was not properly initialized, like

```
yourvariable!.somefield
```

The above assumes that `yourvariable` will not be `null` as this point. If it's `null`, then reality is in conflict with the assumption I have just described.